# Для чего нужен server side rendering в одностраничных приложениях?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

Для чего нужен server side rendering в SPA-приложениях? Кроме как целями СЕО я не могу ответить на этот вопрос.

И как работает React в данных примерах? Ведь как понимаю у нас изначально возвращается реальный DOM, а затем инициализируется JS, который должен совершать манипуляции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пока загрузится первая страница, JS и все это отрендерится может пройти довольно много времени (пользователь смотрит на белую страницу), поэтому первую страницу рендерят на сервере и пользователь увидит её намного быстрее. Именно из-за этой проблемы твиттер когда-то отказался от SPA и вернулся полностью к серверному рендеру, решений типа React тогда не было.

Если react видит DOM и react-checksum совпадает, то он просто навешивает события на DOM ноды и все. Повторный рендер не происходит.